# React ToolBox AppBar menu - how to include menu items?

Tags: react-toolbox

We've just started using React-Toolbox and having a few problems adding menu items to the icon menu. The documentation doesn't have any info on doing this, so does anyone have an example of how to add them when using the AppBar within a component class?

Comment: use `menu icon` as a button and use  [Drawer](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/drawer) or [NavDrawer](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/layout) to add menu items

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've made some progress  - The  onRightIconClick property appears to require a function, so I've created a menu function, which works fine if added directly to the page. But when trying to apply to the onRightIconClick, I always get an error: 'Cannot read property type of null' when used with it . So how do I integrate the menu within the AppBar component? Thanks

Comment: add some code here, along with the error you are getting. It's difficult to solve otherwise

Comment: I think I figured out the issue - the app bar isn't setup to include dropdown type menu's from icons, it expects the drawer style. We are using it for a desktop app to begin with and toolbox seems far more tuned to a mobile app. I've worked around the problem and built a custom component.